# What's a gender-neutral way of referring to a nurse?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

In Japanese there is a word called "看護師" which basically is a gender-neutral way of referring to a *nurse*.

I was wondering, Is there such an equivalent word in English; that is, is there a gender-neutral way of referring to a *nurse*?

Comment: I doubt that 看護師 is really sex-neutral, even if it is grammatically gender-neutral. (The latter is necessarily so since there isn't gender in Japanese.) You could probably devise a test that could be presented to samples of Japanese subjects which would reveal that the stereotype image that most of them form in their mind in response to the word 看護師 is female.

Comment: I agree with @Kaz: 看護師 (*kangoshi*) just means something like "caretaker professional," which is what *nurse* has come to mean in the U.S., but when someone says *nurse* here they get an image of a woman. And if you Google images for [看護師](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%9C%8B%E8%AD%B7%E5%B8%AB&num=50&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS437US437&prmd=imvnsl&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=ga2ZT9jRDpOf6QGq3rXEBg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1115&bih=816), you mainly see female pictures.

Comment: General Reference. Google ["he is a nurse"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he+is+a+nurse%22&oq=%22he+is+a+nurse%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.21.532.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.CmxyHZmFkBQ&pbx=1&biw=1237&bih=902&cad=cbv&sei=C7CZT8q9NKfR4QTlnIDFBg#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he+is+a+nurse%22&oq=%22he+is+a+nurse%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3...5103.5103.2.5431.1.1.0.0.0.0.44.44.1.1.0.YNgfVRSzgCU&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c5d78a5637935dd9&biw=1237&bih=902) gets 12M hits.

Comment: 'kangoshi' is a newer and more gender-neutral alternative to the original 'kangofu' (看護婦). While Japanese doesn't have grammatical genders, the final kanji 婦 contains the sign for 'woman' (女) and is thus, to a Japanese reader, definitely female. Replacing 'fu' with 'shi' (師) thus makes the word less 'gendered'.

Comment: @hallvors: The point is, many words for occupations get associated with a gender anyway, as the Google image search shows. There are probably female lumberjacks and there are plenty of female soldiers, but the archetypal *first-thought* image would be of a man for both of those. Compare that with *receptionist* — a gender-neutral noun with strong female associations.

Comment: @Robusto: Good point, and _secretary_ may have even stronger female undercurrents than _receptionist_, whereas _administrative assistant_ would seem more gender-neutral. Rightly or wrongly, _nurse_ may have trouble shedding its feminine association, and the fact that women _nurse_ their babies probably won't help.  (I might nurse a drink, but I could never nurse a baby.)

Comment: @Robusto Sure, but this is a place where intentional language "design" meets associations-by-usage patterns. So the Japanese intentionally replaced one character / sound with another in an effort to create a new word less gender-biased than the old one. So most users of modern Japanese will presumably be aware that two words exist for "nurse" and the intention behind this. Your Google Images search will easily uncover the reality that females outnumber males in the nursing profession (also in Japan) but it definitely won't reveal language users' awareness of linguistic intentions.. :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The word **nurse** is gender-neutral in modern English.

Comment: Doesn't the word *nurse* have a female connotation ?

Comment: @Pacerier no. It used to, but that was about 50 years ago.

Comment: Yes, it definitely still has a female connotation and *male nurse* is sometimes required to overcome that.

Comment: @Kaz So instead of using a *male nurse*, what's a more gender-neutral synonym to the word *nurse*?

Comment: It can carry a female connotation, but it need not have it—nursing is the profession, and if you are in that profession, you are a nurse. The female connotation is baggage that, if not shed, is being shed.

Comment: @Pacerier - At least in the United States, nurses are often referred to by their degree/level of qualification: Licensed Vocational Nurse (LVN), Registered Nurse (RN), etc.  I believe that referring to someone as an LVN or RN is as gender-neutral as it is possible to be.

Comment: It's the nursing profession that has a "female connotation" based on traditional gender roles. The word itself has no such connotations.

Answer (score 11):

Note that *gender* isn't sex. It's a linguistic/grammatical notion and there are languages with more than three genders:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#More_than_three_grammatical_genders

English doesn't have a grammatical gender, outside of pronouns like he, she it. The Wikipedia article above gives a citation for this claim: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#cite_note-enc-0

What's at issue here is that there is a lingering *sex-role stereotype* attached to *nurse*. This is not easy to expunge, and is still carried to some extent even by a politically-correct term such as *health care professional*. Some people will imagine a woman when they hear *health care professional*, without any further context, and there is nothing that can be done about that. Simply adding *health care* to *professional* brings in stereotypes related to the profession in which the supporting, caregiving roles are occupied largely by women.

Also, consider the word "stripper": *paint stripper*, *stripper*, *male stripper*. You can see there is no gender in the word word itself: a stripper is something or someone that strips, transitively or reflexively.

Comment: Wow *gender* isn't *sex*, that's really something to think about!

Comment: *Gender* is sometimes used as a euphimism for *sex*. For instance "Selecting the gender of a child is controversial." People are more comfortable saying *gender* rather than *sex*. But gender isn't sex. In some languages, inanimate (and therefore sexless) things have gender: they can be he, she, it, or other possibilities. French: *la baguette*.

Comment: Isn't it true that the word gender has two meanings, so it can mean either 1) *sex*, or 2) the grammatical *gender* ?

Comment: Yes, but in this website we should know better. :)

Comment: @Pacerier. Actually, your definition (1) of *gender* isn't exactly the same as sex either, but that's somewhat off-topic.

Comment: While gender (for people rather than language) *is* used as a euphemism for sex by some, it definitely is not the same. Even without considering gender *identity* (in terms of people who identify with the gender associated with the "opposite" sex, or people who express less-common gender identities like *gender-queer*), there are also people who are *intersex* (not explicitly male or female in sex) and attaching a pre-determined gender to their biology is obviously problematic.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Furthermore, there is no conclusive objective test for the sex of a human.

Comment: @JonPurdy Is that really the case? Or is it more like there are tests which are objective and conclusive for most humans, but not for a minority?

Comment: @Kaz Even leaving aside self-identification, biologically identifying the sex of a person can be tricky when aneuploidy (= unnormal chromosome count) comes into play. And let’s not even get started with transgender. Who said anyway that biological sex is defined by chromosomes? Sometimes this is helpful but far from always, even in a purely biological context.

Comment: -1 I see no actual answer to the question here.

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering, Is there such an equivalent word in English?
>
> i.e. What's a gender-neutral way of referring to a nurse ?

You don't really need an equivalent word. The word *nurse* means both men or women who do that job.

If certain people associate the word with women, that's their personal view. It does not mean that the word itself is particular to women, at least not in modern times within the UK.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that "nurse" is gender-neutral, use it.  If you believe that "nurse" has a female connotation, say "nurse (male or female)".  The solution doesn't have to be a single word.

Answer (score -2):

The terms commonly used in journals and literature tend to be "practitioner", "clinician" and "healthcare professional" all of which the profession of nurse falls under, but certainly do not have a female connotation. (E.g. The Journal for Nurse Practitioners)

Comment: Yes, but none of those mean "nurse".

Comment: While these are all gender neutral terms these are too broad to refer specifically to a nurse. These are blanket terms that apply to a wide variety of healthcare workers. *Nurse* is and should be a gender neutral term.

Comment: To someone who instantly imagines a woman upon hearing the word "nurse", some of these words do have the conntation, in particular "health care practitioner". What is that? It is a nice way of saying "someone who didn't go all the way to become an M.D.".  More often than not, a woman.